# Pixel and Tonic Assets add-on -- Workarounds for Assets File Chooser Not Allowing a Directory to be Selected?

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, assets, pixelandtonic, feature-request

See subject. Wondering if anyone has needed the ability to select an Assets directory
(e.g. on Rackspace) for a channel field?

Some ideas:

Method (1) (ugly): use the supplied Assets file chooser for a channel field, choose a 
file, and other code that uses this just ignores the filename. This is confusing for an 
EECP user creating/editing such a channel entry. The "display settings" for such a field 
does not let one hide the "Name" column either, which seems to be hard-coded in assets 
in quite a few places and not easily changeable. Hiding that field just makes it a 
little less confusing for an EECP user. A further strike against this is it also 
requires a file exist in any directory to be chosen.

Method (2): Write a channel field add-on, can likely be as easy as getting the 
directories from an Assets source (which are in the EE DB, since Assets indexes things) 
and presenting a drop-down list of directories for a given Assets source. This is likely
best, except for (4).

Method (3): Text field, and can validate is an actual path. Dead simple, but is a pain 
because would require the EECP user type in and already know the path name ahead of
time.

Method (4): (Hi P&T!) Is such a feature planned in Assets? Would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your second suggestion (a custom fieldtype which lists all directories and subdirectories indexed by Assets) is the best option absolutely.

Send feature requests to support@pixelandtonic.com.